# Initialization a variable in a few bits

Tags: c#

Hy all, please tell me how in C# initialize variable in a several bits, for example in visual C it has been done as:

```
char variablename:3;
```

Comment: Thank's you) its so sad(

Comment: No it is not sad at all. Provide a use-case to get alternatives.

Comment: My alternative is an idea proposed @Hans Passant, by using bitvector32 structure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bit fields is a C language feature, it doesn't exist in C#.  Consider the BitArray class or the efficient BitVector32 structure instead.  Beware that bit fields are expensive, favor byte or int if perf matters.